# Is there a way to have respondents attach a file to a form response?

Tags: google-forms, attachment

I need to have a form with the normal questions, in addition to having respondents attach or download a file. Is this possible?

Comment: If the answer addressed your question, you should accept it so others can benefit as well -as per [site guidelines](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). :)

Answer (score 1):

Allow responders to **attach** a file.

**Google Forms does not allow you this option**. However.
You could create a web app by using [Google Apps Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/).
Keep in mind though that a web app form is basically a website.

---

Allow responders to **download** a file.

You could do this by entering the download link in one of your descriptions text (*Please right-click to download the file: [http://mysite/thisfile.zip](http://mysite/thisfile.zip_)*).
Or you could include the link at the *Thank You* screen shown after submitting the form.